# How do I format a number with a leading zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My time is updating in realtime with the following function:

```js
    var nIntervId;

    function updateTime() {
        nIntervId = setInterval(flashTime, 1000*2);
    }

    function flashTime() {
        var now = new Date();
        var h = now.getHours();
        var m = now.getMinutes();
        var s = now.getSeconds();
        var time = h + ':' + m;
        $('.time').html(time);
    }

    $(function() {
        updateTime();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <span class="time" style="margin-left:20px"></span>
```

Problem ist, that it is displaying `11:9`  instead if `11:09`

Comment: The question title should be "How do I format a number with a leading zero".

Comment: @PeterB Yes, true. Will change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem ist, that it is displaying 11:9 instead if 11:09

You could add a condition like :

```
var m = now.getMinutes() < 10? '0'+now.getMinutes(): now.getMinutes();
```

That will add the `zero` if the minutes are lower than 10.